# Rollup summary on objects without relationship

Tags: apex, trigger

I am looking for roll summary Triggers for two Objects, who are not directly related, but are both children of `Account`.

> Object A__c :  Account, TextField__c  & NumberField__c

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you go look at Andrew Fawcett's [Declarative Lookup Roll-up Summary Trigger repository](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) on Github and use that code as a basis for creating any custom code you may need to write. I don't fully understand the criteria you describe. It's unusual to do a roll-up on objects where two fields match, particularly since those values can change.

Comment: Thank you your response.. I want  to Sum  this field NumberField__c only if the Value is same in TextField__c from (Object A) & TextField1__c ( Object B ) and should display in  Totalsum__c . I want to display the Sum value in report

Comment: Again, the DLRS would be the code to use to start from. Conditional summary code is unusual, but not unheard of. E.G. what if Object B's text value changes? You have no trigger that fires on Object B. You may want to consider that and add a trigger for updates to Object B.